# Space between a elements

Tags: html, css, whitespace, margin

I have 4 `img`s inside `a`s and when i run the code i see a white space between them. I tried removing margins, padding and whitespaces but none of these worked.

code: http://jsfiddle.net/FranLegon/ukgL07b2/

```
<head>
    <style>
    .social {
    width: 3%;
    left:0;
    top:30%;
    position:fixed;
}
    .social a img {
    width: 100%;
} 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="social">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/franlegon"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/6UdcCOJ4OlvOp2g_MSFQ0pcz7M1FSBkwzRQXb1medNVAAQ_TQiJMPHfc7FynLc6NsW8rEObImIQ=w1342-h537" style="
"> </a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/franlegon"><img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/GFoFtbx7B5Cki8LL2Vwg4vucxlObHVypLNS6RVS0Tewio1HZ1sQUjs-YOC2lch4uaGUrfxEu87I=w1342-h537"> </a>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/107921190901479399752/about"><img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/YOm9fO4pxI7FWLpFJq1ctttgYjiq8LGFZzywhqBSc1La4OsG_x-AIzt6qFomM_OV0EuFfOW0nIg=w1342-h537"> </a> 
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/franlegon"><img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/AheHv00gT0ScM4n94xqiNHvNa7S2d_gkTnoK8PGfIPom66rPMsyllogb8vehdvoNNZhBeQFUnG4=w1342-h537"> </a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't see the images (error 403 forbidden). Can you please edit the JSFiddle? Have you tried to remove the spaces, newlines, etc. between `</a>` and `<a>`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ukgL07b2/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why an image inside a div has an extra space below the image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: @A.L why do you need to see the images? you can see them in the code. As I said i've already tried removing whitespaces.

@DanielPinzon his problem was different because he used `div`s which already have block display by default. It's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image do not work as a block, you need to make it work...

```
.social a img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```